# Need to create a new custom object record (new order) based on the current page record (current order) using custom VF

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-object, controller-extension

I have an Order custom object which consists of order items. Once this order is delivered to a a store for a customer, I want to add a button (on the order) that allows the employee to reorder any items that were not available to ship to the customer. Thus, it just needs to show a page with all of the items that weren't available with a button for each item to 'Reorder Item' and then a final button to 'Create New Order'. I don't care if the new order is created first and then the items are added with each 'Reorder Item' button click or if the order is created with the items added upon the click of the 'Create New Order' button.

Below is my controller and VF page that I have thus far. I need help passing the new orderId between the controller and VF page. I know that the following won't work because I'm stuck with how to pass things back and forth. I also need to assign the same customer from the original order to the reorder (hence the commented out code that gives me an error:

```
//newOrder.customer__r.name = items.order__r.customer__r.name;
```

Any ideas?

Controller:

```
global with sharing class SCE_ReshopOrderController{

public string recordId {get; set;}
public string oldOrderCust {get; set;}
public List <Order_Item__c> items {get; set;}
private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

public SCE_ReshopOrderController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    controller = stdController;
    items = [SELECT id, name, quantity__c, status__c, order__r.name, item_name__r.item_number__c, 
             item_name__r.name, item_name__r.department_name__c, item_name__r.full_upc__c, item_name__r.upc__c, 
             item_name__r.image_url__c, item_name__r.price__c, item_name__r.aisle_location__c, order__r.customer__r.name 
             FROM order_item__c WHERE Order__r.id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') 
             AND (status__c = 'Not In Stock' OR status__c = 'Not Received')
             ORDER BY item_name__r.department_name__c, name];
    recordId = controller.getId();

    Order__c newOrder = new Order__c ();
    if(items.size() != 0 ){
        newOrder.status__c = 'Processing';
        //newOrder.customer__r.name = items.order__r.customer__r.name;
        insert newOrder;
    }

}

//mark item for order
@remoteAction
    global static void reorderItem(String orderItemId) {
        Order_Item__c orderItem = [SELECT id, name, status__c, quantity__c, Order__r.id FROM Order_Item__c WHERE id = :orderItemId limit 1];
        orderItem.status__c = 'Not Picked';
       // update orderItem;

    }

//create new order for reorder
@remoteAction
    global static void createOrder(String orderId) {
        Order__c order = [SELECT id, name, status__c FROM Order__c WHERE id = :orderId limit 1];
        order.status__c = 'Ready to Pick';
        update order;
    }
```

}

VF Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Order__c" extensions="SCE_ReshopOrderController">
         <script>
            var orderId = "{!recordId}";
         </script>
    <!-- page to list merchandise -->
     <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
         <script>
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page-1', function(){

                 //mark item for reorder
                $('.button-reorder').click(function(e) {
                    var item = $(this).attr("item");
                    console.log("reordered item: " + item);
                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                        '{!$RemoteAction.SCE_ReshopOrderController.reorderItem}',
                        item, function (result, event) {
                            if (event.status) {
                                }
                            //update page to show reordered
                            $("#status-"+item).html('<h3>Reorder</h3>');
                            $.mobile.loading("hide");
                            },
                        {escape: true}    
                    );
                });

                $(document).on('click', '#button-submit', function() {                    
                    //create new order
                    console.log("button-sumbit clicked");
                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                        '{!$RemoteAction.SCE_ReshopOrderController.createOrder}',
                        orderId, function (result, event) {
                            if (event.status) {
                                }
                            //navigate back
                            sforce.one.back(true);
                            },
                        {escape: true}    
                    );
                });
            }); // end pagebeforeshow

         </script>

         <div data-role="content">
             <h1>Unfulfilled Merchandise</h1>
             <a id="button-submit" name="button-submit" data-role="button" href="#" data-theme="b">Create New Order</a>
             <hr/>
             <apex:repeat value="{!items}" var="item">
                 <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
                     <div class="ui-block-a">
                         <h2>Department:&nbsp;{!item.item_name__r.department_name__c}</h2>
                         <h3>{!item.item_name__r.name}</h3>
                         <h3>Quantity:&nbsp;{!item.quantity__c}</h3>
                         <p> UPC:&nbsp;{!item.item_name__r.upc__c}<br/>
                         </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" name="button-reorder" item="{!item.id}" class="button-reorder" href="#">Reorder</a>                         
                        <div id="status-{!item.id}" >
                            <h3>{!item.status__c}</h3>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="ui-block-a"><div style="text-align:center">
                         <img src="{!item.item_name__r.image_URL__c}" width="250" />
                     </div></div>
                     <div class="ui-block-b"><div style="text-align:center">
                         <br/>
                         <canvas id="{!item.name}" width="1" height="1" style="border:1px solid #fff;visibility:hidden"></canvas>
                     </div></div>                         
             </div> <!-- grid-a -->
             <hr/>
         </apex:repeat>
        </div>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to save yourself a lot of trouble by simply cloning the existing order and using that as a starting point. Also, until you "save", from what I can see, it doesn't appear as though you'll have a new OrderID (your RecordID), so you'll need to then do an update (or else a delete if there isn't going to be a new order).